# wpf textbox tootip binding itself value

Tags: wpf, binding

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel Background="Gray">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={ TextBox.Text}}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>


</Style>
```

========================================

```
"<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={ TextBox.Text}}"/>"
```

I want to bind the textbox text to the Textbox's property such as text or something.
but you know what I think above dose't work.
can you help me ,thank you very much

Answer (score 31):

Here is the answer

```
<TextBox Text="Now is the winter of our discontent Made glorious summer by this sun of York; And all the clouds that lour'd upon our house In the deep bosom of the ocean buried."
    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"
    Width="100" Margin="10"/>
```

It was found at https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/08/29/374-using-a-tooltip-to-display-the-full-contents-of-a-textbox/

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
        <DockPanel Background="Gray">
          <ContentPresenter/>
        </DockPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: thankyou very much.it's work ,but I am trying to add more info in the tootip
so I add ablow codes but it's doesn't work angain.the msdn is difficult to understand
 <Setter.Value>
                <DockPanel Background="Gray">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox,AncestorLevel=2,Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Text}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Setter.Value>